# How do i access the web application from another machine

Tags: jsf, weblogic, jdeveloper

I have deployed the web application in my system using the integrated weblogic server in the jdeveloper 11 g.
But when I start the server and try to access the home page from another system using my ip , I am not getting the page.
Should I be doing any configuration for the same?

Comment: what error does it give? can you please provide more information?

Answer (score 0):

i would check to see if you can ping the ip successfully where the application is running from the other system.  if ping is successful i would then check to see if you can telnet successfully to ip using the port jdeveloper is listening on.  if ping or telnet is unsuccessful depending on your system you might want to check your firewall/iptable rules.